# Sampler not Wrapping texture

Tags: c#, directx, shader, hlsl, sharpdx

I got a shader with an non functioning sampler inside that i currently overwrite with a temporal fix. but i finnaly find the issue and fix this shader.

basically i have my texture and sampler defined like this (using `Profile = fx_4_0;`, also tryed many other ways of defining a sampler e.g: dx9 way using sampler_state, etc.):

```
Texture2D dirtTexture;
SamplerState WrapSampler {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};
```

and i also tryed other variations of writing the same sampler but it allways ending up using the default sampler that clamps the texture coordinates.

and for reading the texture:
`Output.Color = dirtTexture.Sample(WrapSampler, PSIn.TextureCoords);`

my temporal fix, that makes the texture wrap correctly (for whatever reason), is the following:
`_effect.Parameters["WrapSampler"].SetResource(GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates.LinearWrap);`

full shader if needed: http://pastebin.com/tLJi1Uwd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the samplerstate outside of the shader, so your temporal fix is the correct way to do it.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/issues/detail?id=404)